# How do I use glib in kdevelop?

Tags: c, glib, kdevelop

I'm using Kdevelop 4.0 to make a new app, and now I'm trying to include the glib but I cannot do it.

I have installed via apt-get install in Ubuntu 10.04 and it's installed in /usr/include/glib-2.0, but when I try to include the library with

```
    #include <glib.h>
```

and try to compile it, it tells me that "such file doesn't exists".

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: This question really has nothing to do with KDevelop, but since you mentioned it, I highly recommend updating your KDevelop version from the one distributed with Ubuntu (4.0), if for no other reason than stability.

Comment: Actually this question is perfectly right. At least for Eclipse there is a plug-in that manages pkg-config settings, maybe some similar plugin exists for KDevelop too?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the path to the glib libraries and headers to your compiler.

glib provides the pkg-config script to generate what you need. To compile correctly, you would need to do something like the following:

```
cc `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` hello.c -o hello
```

This answer is basically a quick summary of what is provided in the glib documentation here:

http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.28/glib-compiling.html

I'm not familiar with KDevelop, but if it's like Eclipse or Visual Studio, there is a menu for adding libraries and include folders to a project. Try the following:

- Run `pkg-conf --cflags glib-2.0`
- Add output to include directories for your project.
- Run `pkg-conf --libs glib-2.0`
- Add output to libraries path for your project.

A quick look on google suggests that you can find these menus at the following locations:

- Include Directories

  - Automake manager> options> Includes> Directories
- Library Directories

  - Automake Manager > Options >Libraries > Link Libraries

Comment: Thanks! I Know this, but what I'm trying to do is using it with KDevelop which doesn't find the correct file! Thanks!

Comment: I think this is for older versions because I cannot find this. Thanks!